# VerifyError in Java EE generated class

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, verifyerror

I need to create a java bean (Singleton) where I can listen to a socket.
I try to invoke an @Asynchronous method from @PostConstruct, but I get an exception:

```
@Singleton
@Lock(LockType.READ)
@DependsOn("CalculationServerStorage")
public class TaskManager {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        select();
    }

    @Asynchronous
    public void select() {...}
}
```

Exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: class com.asu.dmsaas.calculationserver.ejb.__EJB31_Generated__TaskManager__Intf____Bean__ overrides final method getName.()Ljava/lang/String;
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
                ... 44 more
```

How can I do it?

Comment: A `VerifyError` is caused by an invalid class file. It has nothing to do with selectors, NIO, whatsoever. In this case you've somehow managed to override a final method. Recompile everything and redeploy.

Comment: Thank you, you are right. I really override getName method.
But now, the same code has blocked during deploying.
It invoke a select method from java.nio.selector...